# Equality operator to compare non int types

Tags: ocaml

I recently updated from OCaml 4.03 to OCaml 4.13 for my project. One change is that I am getting a type error when checking for equality between non-int types. For example, for `floats` I get this:

*Error: This expression has type float but an expression was expected of type int*

I can solve this by explicitly using `Float.(f0 = f1)`. But I get the same problem with custom types. E.g.:

```
utop # type e = X | Y
utop # let a = X;;
val a : e = X
utop # let b = Y;;
utop # X = Y;;
Error: This expression has type e but an expression was expected of type int
```

What is the correct way of handling this scenario? `Stdlib.(a = b)` works but feels cumbersome since a polymorphic equality operator is so commonly used.

Comment: Are you using the Jane Street `Base` library? It has non-polymorphic comparisons.

Comment: For me, using OCaml 4.13.1 your code works without issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not an inherent behavior of OCaml. It comes from Jane Street Base (and presumably other modules from Jane Street), which override some of the built-in polymorphic functions.

The idea is that there are risks involved with the built-in polymorphic comparisons that can be surprising if you aren't careful.

To get the usual OCaml polymorphic comparison operators you can use the `Polymorphic_compare` module. Here is a link to the documentation of Jane Street Base (if that's what you're using): [Base at Jane Street](https://ocaml.janestreet.com/ocaml-core/latest/doc/base/index.html)